# ¿Cómo volver a "1" el ID auto increment sin perder registros anteriores?

Tags: mysql, sql

¿Cómo podría hacer en caso de que me pidan como requerimiento que al cambio del año los folios  (ID) que son auto incrementables (tipo int)  vuelvan a comenzar desde 1 sin perder los registros anteriores?

Necesito encontrar una solución sobre los folios, como fue cambio de año requieren que los folios de nuevo comiencen desde uno. ¿Cómo podría hacer eso?

Dentro de mi_tabla están los campos:

- folioSalida int (PK) auto-increment
- idCliente fk int
- fechaSalida date
- totalSalida double

Pensé en hacer una llave compuesta, añadiendo un campo año y que fuera conformada tanto por folioSalida y año y así utilizarlo, por ejemplo: folioSalida 1 y año 19. así para no repetir y quedaría así: 119, 219, 319 y con select mostrar solo el folio, el problema que no se como hacer la condición para que cuando cambie de año de nuevo reinicie el 1.

Comment: si el folio es PK no puede reiniciarse, ya que se repetirian las PK.. la PK tiene que ser folio año.. y entonces hablamos de otra cosa totalmente diferente...

Comment: porque no podes usar un autonumerico. Tenes que llevar la cuenta a mano.

Answer (score 1):

Lo más flexible es que las Primary Key sean de uso exclusivamente interno, ni siquiera se debería mostrar al usuario excepto para tareas de mantenimiento.

Puedes optar por diversas medidas:

**Primary key compuesta**

Añadir una segundo campo a la Primary Key, en tu caso podrías usar el año, pero usa el año completo (2019)  no los últimos dígitos (19) como indicas, te facilitará la vida y no creo que tengas que estar tan ahorrativo de espacio.
Como te indica @gbianchi deberás llevar el recuento a mano, pues no vale el autoincremental. Esto lo puedes gestionar desde la aplicación o desde un procedimiento almacenado.

**Tabla intermedia**

Dependiendo del uso que le des a esa Primary Key podrias tener una tabla intermedia (**indice_folios**) para saber en que folio empieza cada año, así cuando tengas que mostrar el campo *folioSalida*  bastará que le restes el indice del año al que corresponde el registro (el indicado en *fechaSalida*).

**Campo adicional**

Puedes crear un campo nuevo (*numeroFolio*) que será el numero de folio que ve el usuario, puedes inicializarlo con el valor actual de *folioSalida* y a partir de ahora gestionar tu su valor.

> En cualquier caso deberás llevar una gestión manual del número de
>   folio dependiendo del año.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta @Fly, me ayudó mucho entender esto... Soy nuevo y me cuesta un poco.